# Check array values in in_array

Tags: php

I am using this code to check if one of the values in the arrays are present:

```
<?php
if (in_array($_SESSION['bedrijf'], array(
    "torza",
    "thure",
    "mb"
)) && in_array($_SESSION['user_type'], array(
    "beheerder",
    "administratie",
    "kantoor",
    "werkplaats"
))) {
    echo 'execute script';
}
?>
```

But now the script is not executed or any errors given.

`print_r($_SESSION['bedrijf'])` gives `Array ( [0] => mb [1] => thure [2] => torza )`

`print_r($_SESSION['user_type'])` gives `beheerder`

Comment: You really have not given us very much to go on here. No errors reported?

Comment: Are both of your sessions set? Are you getting any errors? Have you ensured you have provided a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve), and [**tried something yourself**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)? For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: If statements looks fine, are you sure your $_SESSION variables are set correctly?

Comment: '$_SESSION['bedrijf']' is always an array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will not find the needle array as a sub-array in the haystack.  If `$_SESSION['bedrijf']` is always an array, then check for an intersection (at least 1 match):

```
if (array_intersect($_SESSION['bedrijf'],
                    array("torza","thure","mb")) &&
    in_array($_SESSION['user_type'],
             array("beheerder","administratie","kantoor","werkplaats")))
{
    echo 'execute script';
}
```

Comment: array_intersect returns an array. Not an int. Wrap it in a `count()`

Comment: Intersection is 3 is the number of values of the array, correct? The number of values can be different per user

Comment: @Muiter What is it you are really looking for? Do you just want to know if **all** the values are present? Or if **any** of the values are present

Comment: Removed the `== 3` so if any values are present, or `> 0`.

Comment: If any of the values are present.

Comment: Yes, i had already removed it and deleted the count comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

Because your `$_SESSION['bedrijf']` contains an array, its possible to get your result with the following code.

```
 <?php
    $allowScript = false;
    if(is_array($_SESSION['bedrijf']))
    {
        foreach($_SESSION['bedrijf'] as $bedrijf)
        {
            if (in_array($bedrijf, array("torza","thure","mb")) && in_array($_SESSION['user_type'], array("beheerder", "administratie", "kantoor","werkplaats")
            {
                $allowScript = true;
                // Execute Script!
            }
        }
    }

    if($allowScript === TRUE)
    {
        // Execute script
    }
    else
    {
        // Not allowed
    }

    ?>
```

Comment: Might want to add a `break` when found.